# How to get cumulative sum in ledger stock

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I want to cumulative sum in ledger stock but I don't know how to get so
please help me.

**Current output**

```
LedgerID    ProductId   TType   ProductName  Credit   Debit    Stock    TDate
1              1        LGR     CAUSTIC        20      0       20   22/03/2018
12             1        GRN     CAUSTIC        10      0       30   26/03/2018
13             1        DA      CAUSTIC        0       15      30   26/03/2018
14             1        DA      CAUSTIC        0       15      30   26/03/2018
15             1        RM      CAUSTIC       10       0       40   26/03/2018
```

**Required output**

```
LedgerID    ProductId   TType   ProductName  Credit   Debit    Stock    TDate
1              1        LGR     CAUSTIC        20      0       20   22/03/2018
12             1        GRN     CAUSTIC        10      0       30   26/03/2018
13             1        DA      CAUSTIC        0       15      15   26/03/2018
14             1        DA      CAUSTIC        0       15      00   26/03/2018
15             1        RM      CAUSTIC        10      0       10   26/03/2018
```

**My Query**

```
select LedgerID,ProductId,TType,ProductName,
isnull(sum(case when DC = 'C' then Qty end),0) Credit,
ISNULL(sum(case when DC = 'D' then Qty end),0) Debit,
(select ISNULL(sum(case when DC = 'C' then Qty end),0) as Stock from LedgerMaster as b where b.LedgerID <= a.LedgerID and b.ProductId=a.ProductId) as Stock,
CONVERT(nvarchar(150), TDate,103) as TDate
from LedgerMaster as a  where ProductId=1
group by  LedgerID,ProductId,TType,ProductName, TDate 
order by ProductName desc, LedgerID asc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished with window function `SUM`. I think code is self-descriptive. The logic is to subtract cumulative sum of `Debit` from cumulative sum of `Credit`.

```
[Stock] = sum(credit) over (partition by productid order by TDate rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
        - sum(Debit) over (partition by productid order by TDate rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

Also, difference of sums is sum of differences, so it can be rewritten as follows:

```
[Stock] = sum(credit - debit) over (partition by productid order by TDate rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

Comment: i am using where ProductId=1 so output perfect but i am no use where so not perfect out put

Comment: i want to product wise cumulative

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about.

Comment: your answer only work for one product like where productid=1 i want to for all product without where condition

Comment: @DenishParvadia you didn't mention that it should be partitioned... Updated solution should work.